# Maximum 1 entity per block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So when I break an `oak_log` block I summon an `area_effect_cloud` with the tag `B.Spawn` at the block I just broke.

Then I use this command to summon a 3x3x3 `area_effect_cloud` cube around the `[tag=B.Spawn]` entity

```
execute at @e[tag=B.Spawn] positioned ~-1 ~-1 ~-1 unless entity @e[tag=B.Cell,distance=...5] run summon area_effect_cloud ~ ~ ~ {Tags:['B.Cell'],Duration:2147483647}
```

Now every `[tag=B.Spawn]` gets killed and every `[tag=B.Cell]` gets the tag of B.Spawn and summons again a 3x3x3 cube around it.

This brings a lot of entities who overlap each other causing 20000 entities in just a 5x5x5 cube.

I need a command which kills all entities within its block so there is only one left per block.

I tried:

```
execute at @e[tag=B.Cell] if entity @e[tag=B.Cell,distance=...99] run kill @e[tag=B.Cell,distance=...99]
```

but this kills all entities.

Comment: So what you actually want is an expanding square of entities going outwards?

Comment: Well if the entity with the tag of B.Cell is in an oak_log block then it'll spread out, if not its deleted.

Comment: So your ultimate goal is to implement something similar to Veinminer or TreeCapitator? Nice idea, I'll see if I can come up with a smarter algorithm than just duplicating and killing stuff all the time. This is pretty similar to something I did at work once.

Comment: I noticied that sumoning an armorstand with the `maker` tag makes `unless entity @e[distance=0]` not work. Not sure if the same applys to effect clouds. Try changing the clouds to armor stands see if it stops summoning too many... (Please, make a backup before trying)

Comment: Ye im trying to make a tree breaker. Also I take precautions so when my world crashes I can fix it in NBTexplorer. and the distance tag works perfectly on area_cloud_effects

Comment: @BrunoRodrigues That is a known bug: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-88533

Answer (score 1):

I will use armour stands in this answer, because I am more familiar with them. It should be pretty easy to switch everything to AECs, if you want that.

There are multiple ways to kill everything except for one entity in a given space, the easiest one is to just tag an arbitrary one (`limit=1`) and then kill all without that tag.
But in your case this constant summoning and killing is actually not required and causes way more lag than necessary. Instead you could check whether an entity already exists in that space before summoning a new armour stand or AEC there. So a VeinMiner/TreeCapitator-like system could for example work like this:

Summon an armour stand at the manually broken block (you seem to have already figured out that part):

```
/summon armor_stand <coordinates> {NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Marker:1,Tags:["vein"]}
```

I will use the tag "vein" for all armour stands that are used in this VeinMiner-like system.

Then repeatedly execute a function as/at all VeinMiner armour stands that have not summoned new armour stands around them yet:

```
/execute as @e[tag=vein,tag=!done] at @s run function vein:summon
```

The function looks like this:

```
execute positioned ~1 ~1 ~1 if block ~ ~ ~ oak_log unless entity @e[tag=vein,distance=...1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Tags:["vein"]}
execute positioned ~1 ~1 ~ if block ~ ~ ~ oak_log unless entity @e[tag=vein,distance=...1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Tags:["vein"]}
execute positioned ~1 ~1 ~-1 if block ~ ~ ~ oak_log unless entity @e[tag=vein,distance=...1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Tags:["vein"]}
execute positioned ~1 ~ ~1 if block ~ ~ ~ oak_log unless entity @e[tag=vein,distance=...1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Tags:["vein"]}
execute positioned ~1 ~ ~ if block ~ ~ ~ oak_log unless entity @e[tag=vein,distance=...1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Tags:["vein"]}
execute positioned ~1 ~ ~-1 if block ~ ~ ~ oak_log unless entity @e[tag=vein,distance=...1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Tags:["vein"]}
execute positioned ~1 ~-1 ~1 if block ~ ~ ~ oak_log unless entity @e[tag=vein,distance=...1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Tags:["vein"]}
execute positioned ~1 ~-1 ~ if block ~ ~ ~ oak_log unless entity @e[tag=vein,distance=...1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Tags:["vein"]}
execute positioned ~1 ~-1 ~-1 if block ~ ~ ~ oak_log unless entity @e[tag=vein,distance=...1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Tags:["vein"]}
execute positioned ~ ~1 ~1 if block ~ ~ ~ oak_log unless entity @e[tag=vein,distance=...1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Tags:["vein"]}
execute positioned ~ ~1 ~ if block ~ ~ ~ oak_log unless entity @e[tag=vein,distance=...1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Tags:["vein"]}
execute positioned ~ ~1 ~-1 if block ~ ~ ~ oak_log unless entity @e[tag=vein,distance=...1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Tags:["vein"]}
execute positioned ~ ~ ~1 if block ~ ~ ~ oak_log unless entity @e[tag=vein,distance=...1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Tags:["vein"]}
# ~ ~ ~ check not necessary
execute positioned ~ ~ ~-1 if block ~ ~ ~ oak_log unless entity @e[tag=vein,distance=...1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Tags:["vein"]}
execute positioned ~ ~-1 ~1 if block ~ ~ ~ oak_log unless entity @e[tag=vein,distance=...1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Tags:["vein"]}
execute positioned ~ ~-1 ~ if block ~ ~ ~ oak_log unless entity @e[tag=vein,distance=...1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Tags:["vein"]}
execute positioned ~ ~-1 ~-1 if block ~ ~ ~ oak_log unless entity @e[tag=vein,distance=...1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Tags:["vein"]}
execute positioned ~-1 ~1 ~1 if block ~ ~ ~ oak_log unless entity @e[tag=vein,distance=...1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Tags:["vein"]}
execute positioned ~-1 ~1 ~ if block ~ ~ ~ oak_log unless entity @e[tag=vein,distance=...1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Tags:["vein"]}
execute positioned ~-1 ~1 ~-1 if block ~ ~ ~ oak_log unless entity @e[tag=vein,distance=...1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Tags:["vein"]}
execute positioned ~-1 ~ ~1 if block ~ ~ ~ oak_log unless entity @e[tag=vein,distance=...1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Tags:["vein"]}
execute positioned ~-1 ~ ~ if block ~ ~ ~ oak_log unless entity @e[tag=vein,distance=...1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Tags:["vein"]}
execute positioned ~-1 ~ ~-1 if block ~ ~ ~ oak_log unless entity @e[tag=vein,distance=...1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Tags:["vein"]}
execute positioned ~-1 ~-1 ~1 if block ~ ~ ~ oak_log unless entity @e[tag=vein,distance=...1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Tags:["vein"]}
execute positioned ~-1 ~-1 ~ if block ~ ~ ~ oak_log unless entity @e[tag=vein,distance=...1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Tags:["vein"]}
execute positioned ~-1 ~-1 ~-1 if block ~ ~ ~ oak_log unless entity @e[tag=vein,distance=...1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Tags:["vein"]}
tag @s add done
```

Explanation: At each of the 26 blocks around the armour stand, a new armour stand is summoned only if there is an oak log there and not another VeinMiner armour stand already. Finally, the armour stand tags itself with "done" so that it doesn't need to check around it anymore in the following iterations.
This already automatically deals with loops and never summons any more armour stand than necessary.

You can stop the iteration when no more armour stands with the tag "`vein`" and without the tag "`done`" exist anymore (or after a certain number of repetitions, in case you apply it to e.g. stone in a default world).

Using a function is actually required in this case. If you first summoned armour stands around all without the "done" tag and then tagged everything with "done", you would also tag the new ones. If you first tagged all with "done" and then summoned new armour stands around all without the tag "done", then of course nothing would happen, because there would be none without the tag left.
Alternatively you would need yet another tag for armour stands that got created in the current round.

Note that a check for `distance=0` does not always work correctly due to the bug [MC-88533](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-88533), so I'm using a radius of 0.1 here.